# AppIcons not showing on device

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside the images.xcassets folder of my project (which started as an empty ios application), I add a new `AppIcon`thingamajig and then added icons for all the app sizes. When I launched the app a few times on my iPhone (not the simulator) it didn't show the app icon that it should have. I'm sure the xcassets folder is working correctly-- for example, I have other images in that folder that I'm accessing from my application (as tab bar icons, for example), so I'm wondering if there's something special I have to do when starting from an empty application to make the AppIcon template work.

Just so you're sure that I've added the icons to AppIcons...

[image]

Comment: I see that you have 26 build warnings. See if any of them are complaining about incorrect image sizes. Note try to always treat these warnings as errors and try to fix them all. Add a screenshot of your build warnings to rule them out

Comment: @SamBudda the problem was that appicons weren't selected in the target properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  BrainLikeADullPencil today i wanted to set APP ICON,LAUNCH SCREEN and SPOTLIGHT FOR MY PROJECT.I did this very easily through the following things

        1.Click your PROJECT(It is in Navigator Area-left side)
        2.If you click that you can see PROJECT and TARGET in the Editor Area(It is in the middle exactly between Navigator Area(left side) and UTILITY Area(right side))
        3.You should click your ProjectName in TARGETS
        4.Then you can see the GENERAL,CAPABILITIES,INFO,BUILD SETTINGS,BUILD PHASES,BUILD RULES.
        5.Click GENERAL whare you can get IDENTITY,DEPLOY INFO,APP ICONS,LAUNCH IMAGES and LINKED FRAMEWORKS AND LIBRARIES

        6.Then choose App Icon where you can see the options(Iphone retina,Iphone normal) for icons(KIND,DIMENSIONS,RESOURCE).
        7.Click right side icon of small size folder.If you click that DROP DOWN BOX appears.
        8.In DROP DOWN BOX "select an iphone non retina and prior app icon" appears.
          Below inside the box your project app icons showing image that what u have copied and have in  a particular folder if you have icons into GROUP FOLDER in your project bundle.
        9.If you have not had that icons, choose ADD OTHER below the drop down box and once you click it asks the icons where you have there(in which part-whether it is documents,desktop or anything)fix that size or edit that icon in pariticular size(what you want) or according to the iphone retina or ipad retina.

       10.Finally select the size of icon what you want and it automatically(size-29,57,114,140...) appears in the RESOURCE.


     IF YOU CAN FOLLOW ABOVE THESE THINGS YOU CAN EASILY FIX IT.TRY THIS ONE.WHEN YOU RUN YOUR PROJECT IN DEVICE IT SHOWS YOUR APP ICON AUTOMATICALLY(1024*1024).
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that you have correct source for App Icons in the target properties.

[image]